# Dynamic HasMany mapping using reflection in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, reflection, fluent

I am using NHibernate 3.3 and trying to map my class hierarchy to DB via reflection as follows:

```
class Parent
{
    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

class Child
{
    public virtual Parent MyParent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentMap : ClassMap<Parent>
{
    public ParentMap()
    {
        Helper.Map(this);
    }
}

public class Helper
{
    public static void Map<T>(ClassMap<T> map)
    {
        foreach (var property in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            // creating lambda x => x.Children

            var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            Expression expr = Expression.Property(arg, property);

            // Func<Parent, IList<Child>> does not work in HasMany()
            // var type = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), property.PropertyType);

            // but IEnumerable works
            var type = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0];  // Child
            type = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(type);         // IEnumerable<Child>
            type = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), type);    // Func<Parent, IEnumerable<Child>>

            dynamic lambda = Expression.Lambda(type, expr, arg);
            map.HasMany(lambda);
        }
    }
}
```

The above is just a simplified example, the main idea is to call HasMany() dynamically for every collection property. I can't seem to find a more direct way of doing that but it works.

The problem is that when I apply Cascade.All() to the map, it results in a StackOverflow exception. When mapping is done manually, this works just fine, so it is not likely to be a mismapping problem.

Comment: Actually it has nothing to do with NHibernate, as it fails when calling Fluently.Configure().Mappings().BuildConfiguration(). I am using the latest version of Fluent (1.3.0.733).